# Get calls from react to exppres in production mode

Tags: reactjs, node.js, axios, cors

I have a react app that sends http requests via axios to a server.
In React I use Redux tool kit to send the request

```
export const getUsers = createAsyncThunk('users/getUsers', 
async (_, {rejectWithValue}) => {  
  try {
    const res = await $.get(`${URL}/users/getUsers`);
    const { allUsers } = res.data;
    return allUsers
  }catch (err) {
    return rejectWithValue(err.response.data.message)
  }
  }
  );
```

On the server I receive the request and send back values that need to be updated on the site:

```
router.get("/getUsers", async (req, res) => {
try {
    const allUsers = await User.find({});
    res.status(200).json({
        title: 'success',
        allUsers
    })
}catch (err) {
    logger.log({
        level: 'error',
        message: err.message,
        actionPage: req.originalUrl,
        additionalInfo: 'שגיאה בשליפת המשתמשים',
    });

    res.status(400).json({
        title: 'error',
        message: 'שגיאה בשליפת המשתמשים'
    })
}
})
```

The behavior of the app is strange.
If I send a get request (as it should be done), in development mode it works fine and in dev mode it does not work (returns an html page).
On the other hand, if I change the method to put, everything works as it should.
(only that I don't want to send an incorrect request).
The definition of cors is:
`app.use( cors({origin: '*'}) );`
I would appreciate it if someone could help me, this is the first site I upload to the server...‏

Comment: Usually, when an HTTP request that is meant to return data (JSON or XML or other) but returns HTML, is that the path is being picked up by the HTTP server in a wildcard route because most likely the application is a SPA and this is something SPA applications need to work properly.  When the SPA HTTP server also serves API, you must make sure the routes are registered in the correct order.  Now, what is "development mode" and how does it differ with "dev mode"?

Comment: In development mode, the server runs on port - 3000 separately, and the general application also runs separately.
I notice two major differences:
1. Difference between get calls and the other types of calls.
2. Difference in the get call itself between development mode and production.
As I mentioned before...

Comment: In addition to your question,
I expect to get an array of objects called allUsers.
I send it in json format.
res.data = html page.
res.data.allUsers = undefined